# Joining Kafka and Cassandra DataFrames in Spark Streaming ignores C* predicate pushdown

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, spark-cassandra-connector

**Intent**

I'm receiving data from Kafka via direct stream and would like to enrich the messages with data from Cassandra. The Kafka messages (Protobufs) are decoded into DataFrames and then joined with a (supposedly pre-filtered) DF from Cassandra. The relation of (Kafka) streaming batch size to raw C* data is [several streaming messages to millions of C* rows], BUT the join always yields exactly ONE result [1:1] per message. After the join the resulting DF is eventually stored to another C* table.

**Problem**

Even though I'm joining the two DFs on the full Cassandra primary key and pushing the corresponding filter to C*, it seems that Spark is loading the whole C* data-set into memory before actually joining (which I'd like to prevent by using the filter/predicate pushdown). This leads to a lot of shuffling and tasks being spawned, hence the "simple" join takes forever...

```scala
def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setAppName("test")      
      .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "xxx")
      .set("spark.cassandra.connection.keep_alive_ms", "30000")
      .setMaster("local[*]")
      
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(10))
    ssc.sparkContext.setLogLevel("INFO")
    
    // Initialise Kafka
    val kafkaTopics = Set[String]("xxx")
    val kafkaParams = Map[String, String](
      "metadata.broker.list" -> "xxx:32000,xxx:32000,xxx:32000,xxx:32000",
      "auto.offset.reset" -> "smallest")
    
    // Kafka stream
    val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, MyMsg, StringDecoder, MyMsgDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, kafkaTopics)      
    
    // Executed on the driver
    messages.foreachRDD { rdd =>
      
      // Create an instance of SQLContext
      val sqlContext = SQLContextSingleton.getInstance(rdd.sparkContext)
      import sqlContext.implicits._
      
      // Map MyMsg RDD
      val MyMsgRdd = rdd.map{case (key, MyMsg) => (MyMsg)}
      
      // Convert RDD[MyMsg] to DataFrame
      val MyMsgDf = MyMsgRdd.toDF()        
        .select(
            $"prim1Id" as 'prim1_id,
            $"prim2Id" as 'prim2_id,
            $...
      )
      
      // Load DataFrame from C* data-source
      val base_data = base_data_df.getInstance(sqlContext)    
      
      // Left join on prim1Id and prim2Id
      val joinedDf = MyMsgDf.join(base_data,
            MyMsgDf("prim1_id") === base_data("prim1_id") &&
            MyMsgDf("prim2_id") === base_data("prim2_id"), "left")
            .filter(base_data("prim1_id").isin(MyMsgDf("prim1_id"))
                && base_data("prim2_id").isin(MyMsgDf("prim2_id")))          
                
      joinedDf.show()
      joinedDf.printSchema()
      
      // Select relevant fields
            
      // Persist
    }
    
    // Start the computation
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
}
```

**Environment**

- Spark 1.6
- Cassandra 2.1.12
- Cassandra-Spark-Connector 1.5-RC1
- Kafka 0.8.2.2

**SOLUTION**

From discussions on the DataStax Spark Connector for Apache Cassandra ML

- [Joining Kafka and Cassandra DataFrames in Spark Streaming ignores C* predicate pushdown](https://groups.google.com/a/lists.datastax.com/forum/#!topic/spark-connector-user/Itt8lpkaGhw)
- [How to create a DF from CassandraJoinRDD](https://groups.google.com/a/lists.datastax.com/forum/#!topic/spark-connector-user/CZZCQncgCQM)

I've learned the following:

> Quoting Russell Spitzer
>
> 1. This wouldn't be a case of predicate pushdown. This is a join on a partition key column. Currently only joinWithCassandraTable supports this direct kind of join although we are working on some methods to try to have this automatically done within Spark.
> 2. Dataframes can be created from any RDD which can have a schema applied to it. The easiest thing to do is probably to map your joinedRDD[x,y] to Rdd[JoinedCaseClass] and then call toDF (which will require importing your sqlContext implicits.) See the [DataFrames documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#inferring-the-schema-using-reflection)  here for more info.

So the actual implementation now resembles something like

```scala
// Join myMsg RDD with myCassandraTable
val joinedMsgRdd = myMsgRdd.joinWithCassandraTable(
  "keyspace",
  "myCassandraTable",
  AllColumns,
  SomeColumns(
      "prim1_id",
      "prim2_id"
  )
).map{case (myMsg, cassandraRow) => 

  JoinedMsg(
    foo = myMsg.foo
    bar = cassandraRow.bar
  )
}

// Convert RDD[JoinedMsg] to DataFrame
val myJoinedDf = joinedMsgRdd.toDF()
```

Comment: Long story short it is not something that can be effectively pushed-down. Predicate you use is dynamic and cannot be expressed as a simple condition without performing queries on record by record basis. Another issue is logical disjunction generated by `isin` which is harder to pushed in general and if nothing changed is not supported in Spark push-downs.

Comment: If you want to avoid shuffles it is probably a better idea to partition and cache `base_data` and partition `MyMsgDF`

Comment: OK, thanks! Yes, that's along the lines what I had suspected. I also thought about collecting prim1_id and prim2_id and use it to narrow down base_data before the join, but if it's impossible to effectively push down predicate lists with isin that won't help either.

Comment: Caching base_data is not actually feasible, high change rate and very large size. Do you see a better way to achieve the original intent?

Comment: You can try to query database directly. `isin` can be effectively rewritten as equality over flattened structure followed by distinct. Regarding `isin` please be sure to double check that - I can be wrong about it.

Comment: OK thanks, will do. I also posted on the spark-cassandra-connector ML and I'll update this post if a solution emerges from that.

Comment: Actually [it looks like it can pushdown `IN`](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/spark-cassandra-connector/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/cassandra/BasicCassandraPredicatePushDown.scala#L9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried joinWithCassandraTable ? It should pushdown to C* all keys you are looking for...

Comment: Actually no, I went straight for the DF approach and didn't consider joinWithCassandraTable. It looks promising though!

Comment: OK, prima vista this looks quite good, but I can't seem to figure out how to convert the resulting CassandraJoinRDD[MyMsg, CassandraRow] into a valid DataFrame again. Any thoughts on this, or should I post a new question?